# Create K8s Secret with Pre-Install hook

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I'm running a Migration Job as a pre-install hook so I created a secret also with DB values as a pre-install hook with lesser weight(should run before migration) and everything works fine, both secret and migration. The problem is the secret is deleted afterwards, which causes the regular pods to fail because it can't find the secret and I can't figure out why.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.secrets.name }}
    chart: {{ .Values.secrets.name }}
  name: {{ .Values.secrets.name }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"
type: Opaque
data:
  {{- range $key, $val := .Values.secrets.values }}
  {{ $key }}: {{ $val }}
  {{- end}}
```

This is what the migration job looks like:

```
kind: Job
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.migration.name }}
    chart: {{ .Values.migration.name }}
  name: {{ .Values.migration.name }}
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-1"
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded,hook-failed
spec:
  backoffLimit: 4
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.migration.name }}
        release: {{ .Values.migration.name }}
    spec:
      containers:
#other config container values
          env:
            - name: APP_ROLE
              value: {{ .Values.migration.role | quote }}
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: {{ .Values.secrets.name }}
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Answer (score 1):

You've been caught using chart hooks in a way that's not really intended.

Have a look at the official helm docs for chart hooks here: [Helm Docs](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/)

Scroll to the very bottom, to "Hook Deletion Policies", you'll read:

> If no hook deletion policy annotation is specified, the before-hook-creation behavior applies by default.

What happens, is helm runs the hook that creates the secret, it creates it, succeeds, goes on to run the next hook ( your migration ) and deletes the secret again before executing that.

Hooks are not intended to create resources that are stay. You could try to hack your way around it by setting a hook-deletion-policy of `hook-failed` to the secret, but i'm not really sure what the outcome will be.

Ideally, you don't run the Migration job of your app in an Init Container of your app. This way, you would create the secrets normally, without a hook, and the init container and the app could reuse the same secret.